# Ruby Script Recursively Creates Deeply Nested Directories

Tags: ruby, windows, recursion, file-handling, directory-structure

I'm working on [a Ruby script](https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any/blob/master/ltx2any.rb), specifically with a method named `copy2tmp`, (copy pasted method definition)

```rb
define_singleton_method(:copy2tmp) do |files|
  files.each do |f|
    if File.symlink?(f)
      # Avoid trouble with symlink loops

      # Delete old symlink if there is one, because:
      # If a proper file or directory has been replaced with a symlink,
      # remove the obsolete stuff.
      # If there already is a symlink, delete because it might have been
      # relinked.
      if File.exist?("#{PARAMS[:tmpdir]}/#{f}")
        FileUtils.rm("#{PARAMS[:tmpdir]}/#{f}")
      end

      # Create new symlink instead of copying
      File.symlink("#{PARAMS[:jobpath]}/#{f}", "#{PARAMS[:tmpdir]}/#{f}")
    elsif File.directory?(f)
      FileUtils.mkdir_p("#{PARAMS[:tmpdir]}/#{f}")
      copy2tmp(Dir.entries(f)\
                  .delete_if do |s| ['.', '..', ]\
                  .include?(s) end.map { |s| "#{f}/#{s}" })
      # TODO: Is this necessary? Why not just copy? (For now, safer and more adaptable.)
    else
      FileUtils.cp(f,"#{PARAMS[:tmpdir]}/#{f}")
    end
  end
end
```

which seems to be creating excessively deeply nested directories, leading to errors. The script is intended for processing LaTeX documents using `ltx2any`. The issue arises when the script attempts to copy files to a temporary directory, but instead, it ends up creating a deeply nested structure like `../folderName/folderName/folderName/...`.

```rb
copy2tmp(Dir.entries('.').delete_if { |f| exceptions.include?(f) })
```

#### What I Have Tried:

1. **Debugging with Recursion Depth:** Added debugging statements to track the recursion depth in `copy2tmp`. This revealed that with each recursive call, the depth increased, and the directory path grew longer (`../folderName/...`).

```
define_singleton_method(:copy2tmp) do |files, depth = 0|
    puts "Debug: Recursion depth #{depth}, files: #{files.inspect}"
# ...
copy2tmp(Dir.entries(f).delete_if do |s| ['.', '..', ].include?(s) end.map { |s| "#{f}/#{s}" }, depth + 1)
# ...
copy2tmp(Dir.entries('.').delete_if { |f| exceptions.include?(f) }, 0)
```

2. **Manual Inspection:** Checked for symbolic links or unusual directory structures that might cause recursive loops. Didn't find any obvious issues here. I have tried running the script in folder with and without spacing in their names.
3. **Checking `copy2tmp` Calls:** Ensured that `copy2tmp` was being called with appropriate parameters and reviewed its recursive calls.
4. **Expectation vs. Reality:** I expected the script to copy files to a temporary directory without creating an unnecessary nested structure. Instead, the script created a deeply nested directory path, leading to a "No such file or directory" error.

#### Question:

I suspect the issue lies in the `copy2tmp` method, either in its definition or the way it is being called. The method is meant to copy files into a temporary directory, but it seems to be causing a recursive loop of directory creation. Can anyone help identify the flaw in the `copy2tmp` method or its invocation that's leading to this problem? Any insights into stopping this unintended recursion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @engineersmnky here is the definiton of `exceptions = ignore + ignore.map { |s| "./#{s}" } + Dir['.*'] + Dir['./.*']`

Comment: @engineersmnky I just tried your suggestion, and the same issue happened.

Comment: @engineersmnky what should the line `copy2tmp(Dir.entries('.').delete_if { |f| exceptions.include?(f) })` change to?

Comment: @engineersmnky I just changed to `copy2tmp(Dir.children('.').reject { |f| exceptions.include?(f) })` mimicking line 24 of your example, and miraculously it seems to work. I am gonna try it on a couple of other simple MWEs before celebrating thought!

Comment: @engineersmnky sent a pull request [here](https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any/pull/126).

Comment: @engineersmnky would be great if you could write an answer below explaining the magic spell you just cast! Some of my Ruby expert friends are not sure how `Dir.children` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it took a bit of digging but I found the crux of your issue.

You are using this line `exceptions = ignore + ignore.map { |s| "./#{s}" } + Dir['.*'] + Dir['./.*']` to attempt to filter out some `ignore` directories as well as all dot files.

In Ruby < 3.1 `Dir['.*']` included the current directory (`'.'`) and the parent directory (`'..'`) so this filter was effective.

As of Ruby 3.1 `Dir['.*']` no longer includes the parent directory (`'..'`). See This [Commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/7dc0511ea4be210f82abb1c82a31aec3a4fe5736)

However `Dir.entries('.')` does include the parent directory.

This means when you call

```
Dir.entries('.').delete_if { |f| exceptions.include?(f) }
```

The parent directory will exist and will not be removed from the `files` array, so you are passing the parent directory to the method. Since this method is recursive and appends the current directory to the file list when recalling itself you were stuck in a never ending loop when running this on ruby 3.1+.

While there are other solutions to fix this issue the simplest and most backwards compatible is to use `Dir.children('.')` because `Dir::children` guarantees it will not include `'.'` or `'..'`

> Returns an array containing all of the filenames except for “.” and “..” in the given directory.

[Working Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/NestedDepthCopy#main.rb)